# Change the type of a dataframe's column in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, converters

I am learning r and I have problem with converting the first column of my dataframe to the type like dataset `USArrests`.

If we view the head dataset of the `USArrests`:

```
           Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
Alabama      13.2     236       58 21.2
Alaska       10.0     263       48 44.5
Arizona       8.1     294       80 31.0
Arkansas      8.8     190       50 19.5
California    9.0     276       91 40.6
Colorado      7.9     204       78 38.7
```

To be honest I dont know the type of the first column like: **Alabama**, **Alaska**,....
If we used `str(USArrests)`:

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Murder  : num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
 $ Assault : int  236 263 294 190 276 204 110 238 335 211 ...
 $ UrbanPop: int  58 48 80 50 91 78 77 72 80 60 ...
 $ Rape    : num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...
```

Here is my dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(12.7557,14.8,17.23)
)
```

View it:

```
1 Breakfast    12.7557
2     Lunch    14.8000
3    Dinner    17.2300
```

My goal is to convert it just like the `USArrest` maybe it look like this:

```
            total_bill
Breakfast    12.7557
Lunch        14.8000
Dinner       17.2300
```

Any help for this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `column_to_rownames` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
dat1 <- dat %>% 
          column_to_rownames('time')
dat1
#         total_bill
#Breakfast    12.7557
#Lunch        14.8000
#Dinner       17.2300
```

---

In `base R`, we can also do the assignment to `row.names` and then assign the column to `NULL`

```
row.names(dat) <- dat$time
dat$time <- NULL
```

---

if we check the `dimnames(USArrests)`, or use `row.names`, it would be clear that it is the row names

```
row.names(USArrests)
#[1] "Alabama"        "Alaska"         "Arizona"        "Arkansas"       "California"     "Colorado"      
#[7] "Connecticut"    "Delaware"       "Florida"        "Georgia"        "Hawaii"         "Idaho"         
#[13] "Illinois"       "Indiana"        "Iowa"           "Kansas"         "Kentucky"       "Louisiana"     
#[19] "Maine"          "Maryland"       "Massachusetts"  "Michigan"       "Minnesota"      "Mississippi"   
#[25] "Missouri"       "Montana"        "Nebraska"       "Nevada"         "New Hampshire"  "New Jersey"    
#[31] "New Mexico"     "New York"       "North Carolina" "North Dakota"   "Ohio"           "Oklahoma"      
#[37] "Oregon"         "Pennsylvania"   "Rhode Island"   "South Carolina" "South Dakota"   "Tennessee"     
#[43] "Texas"          "Utah"           "Vermont"        "Virginia"       "Washington"     "West Virginia" 
#[49] "Wisconsin"      "Wyoming"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If we want to use the new dataframe after converting, what should we do?

Comment: @Ben10 either you can assign `<-` to same object or a new object in `mutate` code and in the second code block, it is already doing the change in the same object